# Android Auto Reject After Change to API 32

Tags: android, sdk, auto

after forcing change to api 32 my app are reject every time i try to publish a new app or an update.
The reason is every time the same
"Your app does not respond (no music played or error message shown) after issuing a voice command."
Or:
Voice commands
Media Apps

Your app does not respond (no music played or error message shown) after issuing a voice command.

Messaging Apps

Your app does not respond to “Reply” when confirming or editing custom messages.

Your app does not respond to “Reply,” "Send It,” or “Cancel”.

Nav Apps

Your app does not respond after issuing a voice command.

But on my side the app works fine!
I cannot able to search what is happened, i've only change the api level to 32.

I've ask to review team an help and they reply that can't help me.
What can i do? this manifest will be ok?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.inmystream.radiox">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application"
            android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />

        <activity
            android:name="stereopesaro.mactechinteractiv.stereopesaro.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.notification.SmallIcon"
            android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <service
            android:name="stereopesaro.mactechinteractiv.stereopesaro.AutoMediaBrowserService"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!--<receiver-->
        <!--android:name="stereopesaro.mactechinteractiv.stereopesaro.Utils.NetworkChangeReceiver"-->
        <!--android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">-->
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
        <!--<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
        <!--</receiver>-->



        <!-- END PushWoosh activities and services -->
        <service android:name="stereopesaro.mactechinteractiv.stereopesaro.radio.RadioService" />
        <!-- A receiver that will receive media buttons and send as
          intents to your MediaBrowserServiceCompat implementation.
          Required on pre-Lollipop. More information at
          https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver -->

        <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            >


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my build grade:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inmystream.studio54radio"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 9
        versionName '1.2'
        multiDexEnabled true

        /*lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }*/

    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {

        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.media:media:1.6.0"
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.1.2'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.0'
}
```

before of api change it works and approved...
thanks who can help me!

help to solve this issue

Comment: Hey, were you able to get it to work?